# Windows Azure CDN :: Javascript, Stylesheet and Images cannot be found (404 Error)

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, https, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm using Windows Azure for hosting my MVC3 project with '/cdn' view that needs to be attached to CDN.
The problem is when I try to navigate via http://azxxxxx.vo.msecnd.net it seems that my browser doesn't find stylesheets, javascripts and images files (Firebug shows 404 not found).
everything works good if I try to navigate to the original way http://mywebsite.cloudapp.net/cdn

I'm looking for a solution that will work behind HTTPS as well  ( https://azxxxxx.vo.msecnd.net ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 404 tells me that you're reaching the CDN and your request is passing through the CDN back to your "origin" web role but for some reason the request isn't matching your web role's expected path/directory structure. (If the CDN wasn't enabled, you'd see a different error message, most likely HTTP 400.)

Be sure that you're navigating to it on the http://az#####.vo.msecnd.net domain without the /cdn/ segment in the path.

These requests will automatically work over HTTPS (assuming you enabled it in the dev portal) once you resolve why the request isn't matching up with the web role's expected path.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, CDN content exists inside Blob storage and is then CDN content is enabled from the Blob storage.

It sounds like you're looking to create CDN content from your Azure Compute URL, which is not correct.

The URLs for CDN enabled content in Blob storage would resemble the following:

- Azure Blob service: http://MyWebsite.blob.core.windows.net/images/
- Azure CDN: http://someLongGuid.vo.msecnd.net/images/

Comment: That used to be the case, but since earlier this year you can use a web role as the origin for CDN content.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09e9ab98-e26f-47b3-a1ea-692c103a3e3a